# how to override translate from a vendor language package

Tags: translate

hello everyone in my case i want to translate some sentences in magento 2.3 wich is already tanslated by a language package or in a module inside the vendor folder , for example i have already a translation for some text but I don't know how to override it , see some examples file location bellow :

web/vendor/imaginaerum/magento2-language-fr-fr/dictionary.csv

web/vendor/mageplaza/magento-2-japanese-language-pack/ja_JP.csv

web/vendor/splendidinternet/mage2-locale-de-de/de_DE.csv

web/vendor/magento/module-quote/i18n/en_US.csv

web/vendor/mageplaza/magento-2-chinese-language-pack/github_contributions.csv

> my question is how to override those translations in my custom module

Comment: you can override the language file in you theme.

Answer (score 2):

You can add your language file under your theme.

EX: app/design/frontend/vendor/theme/i18n/de_DE.csv

This file override all texts from any module.